# A ring without identity: deny the hypothesis

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ a ring without identity. So, $$(R\quad\text{does not have the identity})\Rightarrow (\nexists\;e\in R\;\text{such that}\;ea=a\;\forall a\in R)[\text{It's correct?}].$$

Now, if I found an element $e\in R$ and an element $a\in R$ such that $ea=a$, can I conclude that this contradicts the hypothesis according to which $R$ not have identity?

Comment: For $e$ to be an identity we need $ea = a$ for all $a$, not just one single $a$. So you can‘t conclude what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we write quantifiers **before** statements they are referring. The notation

$$\not\exists e\in R \text{ such that }ea=a\forall a\in R$$

is invalid, simply because it is **unclear**. We don't know if it means

$$\forall a\in R:\not\exists e\in R \text{ such that }ea=a$$
or
$$\not\exists e\in R: \forall a\in R: \text{ such that }ea=a.$$

The two statements above are **not** equivalent, and are in fact very much different. The second statement is much stronger.

---

Second of all, the negation of the statement "$R$ has an identity" is the negation of the statement

$$\exists e\in R: \forall a\in R: ae=e$$

and the negation of this statement is the *second* of the two statements above.

Your argument that if you find some $e,a$ such that $ea=a$, is not enough to prove that $R$ has no identity, since even in rings without an identity, we can set $a=e=0$ and have $ea=a$.

Comment: Thanks for this. You said what I wanted to, and probably better.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. In **any** ring (with or without identity) such elements exist: just take $e=a=0$.